# Manually choose 3g tower in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, modem, 3g, mobile-broadband

I have windows 7 running laptop. I'm now connecting to the Internet via built-in 3g modem. My problem is that I'm located near to two towers. One of them is providing 3g and second one, only edge signal. My computer is very often switching between them, what is a little annoying. Is there any way to manually configure my modem to connect to the better tower?

Comment: Try find a setting to lock the modem to "3G-only" mode in the modem connection app. It's not in Windows 7, in fact as far as Windows concerned your modem is yet another network connection.

Comment: The problem is that actually, there isn't any external app for my modem. I'm using toshiba ultrabook, which has built-in 3g (Ericsson F5521gw for TOSHIBA Mobile Broadband Network Adapter) modem. It's driver is integrated with windows, so I haven't installed any software for it. Is there any kind of universal app for 3g modems?

Comment: Nope. Each to it's own. From a short Google search apparently both Ericsson and Toshiba don't give any app. Locking to 3G is quite an advanced functionality, not even every cellphone have that, so I guess the only solution is to look some cheap 3G cellphone to use instead of your internal modem. Sony feature-phone, the Greenheart series have that function, but you can lookup other brand.

Answer (score 0):

You probably either need to change the 3G roaming setting or update something called the "PRL" in your modem.

Typically this would be done by a utility provided with the software accompanying your modem.  If it's an OEM device the relevant settings may be buried in some Toshiba "network manager" software or similar.  You may try checking the Toshiba website for any utilites available for your model laptop.

PRL updates are pulled from the cellular network and typically can be downloaded automatically, but since it interrupts service usually accompanying software for a cell phone or 3G modem would tell you there's a "service update" for your modem or simliar and require you to approve it before rebooting your device.

You may try seeing if there is a firmware update for your modem as well.